# DAX Aggregation and dynamic filter

Tags: filter, filtering, powerbi, aggregation, dax

I am trying to calculate aggregated data (by Level 1) which respond to slicer selections (on level 2)

Specific Example:

**Data**

```
Level1  Level2  Level3 Data
A         z       q      1
A         zz      q      2
A         zzz     r      3
A         zzzz    r      4
B         z       q      10
B         zz      q      20
B         zzz     r      30
B         zzzz    r      40
```

**Aggregate data by Level1**

Option 1.
Create a table using GroupBy and join it using Level1 (in the relationship tab)

```
Table1_agg =
GROUPBY(
   Table1,
   Table1[Level1],
   "AggL1_Data",sumx(CURRENTGROUP(),Table1[Data])
)
```

Option 2. Use Filter within Table1

```
AggL1_Filter = 
    Calculate(
    sum(Table1[Data]),
    FILTER(
        Table1,
        Table1[Level1]= EARLIER(Table1[Level1])
        )
)
```

Result - aggregation WORKS

[image]

However filtering using the Level2 Slicer does NOT work.

The aggregated data "AggL1_" still shows 10 and 100 where as I want to see 5 (for A) and 50 (for B)

[image]

Help would be greatly appreciated, I've been stuck on this for ages,

Thanks in advance,

dusiod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to use the [ALLSELECTED function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/allselected-function-dax).

```
AggMeasure = CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Data]), ALLSELECTED(Table1[Level2]))
```

[image: Result]

---

**Edit:** If you need to only group by `Level1` (ignoring the filter context for other possible levels), then you need to make an adjustment.

```
AggMeasure = CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Data]),
                 FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Table1),
                     Table1[Level1] IN VALUES(Table1[Level1])))
```

This uses the `ALLSELECTED` function as before to preserve the slicer choices but adds a condition that we only consider rows that match the current `Level1`. For anything in an `A` row, `VALUES(Table1[Level1])` only returns `A` since that's all it sees in its filter context. (The Total row removes all filter context so returns the sum of the two.)

Instead of `IN VALUES(...)` you could use `= MAX(...)` or `= MIN(...)` or `= LASTNONBLANK(...)`.

[image: Result 2]

Comment: Hi Alexis, thanks for your suggestion, I checked it out and:

my original example was too simple. Your solution worked because Level 1 was the only remaining dimension on which the calc could segment.

I've updated the example to more closely reflect the complexity level.

i.e. there are other dimensions in view (level 3) but we only want to groupby / segment by Level1.  In this case the above solution segments by Level & Level 3

Comment: It seems your example was too minimal. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves it,

```
0Measure = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Table1[Data]),
    FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Table1),Table1[Level1]=MAX(Table1[Level1]))
)
```

But can anyone explain why the `FILTER` condition works

```
Table1[Level1]=MAX(Table1[Level1])
```

particularly as the documentation for MAX states that the function ignores logical values and text...

Comment: I'm pretty sure more recent updates allow `MAX` to handle text and Booleans. Not sure what particular documentation you're referring to, but I think it's outdated for recent versions of Power BI.